# Bazaar page display of jquery mobile, phone gap, ios

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have an app that I've uploaded to the Apple itunesconnect store.  I had locked the XCode compiler to only display in portrait mode (and 180 degrees of that) and on iPhones (no landscape nor iPads in this version).  I've tested it both in all Apple's simulators and on an iPhone 4.  The relevent code is query mobile and I've wrapped it with with PhoneGap.

Here is a screen shot which shows the appearance on both the simulator and my iPhone: [image with no problems http://html6store.com/AppStoreOriginal.png](http://html6store.com/AppStoreOriginal.png).
Here is my complete code to generate this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=device-dpi' />

<title>Shots Lite</title>
<link href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function procClick(a) {

  if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
    {
      sessionStorage.shotsSelectedOption=a;
    }
  else
    {
      //document.getElementById("page").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
      alert('Since your browser doesn\'t support web storage, just transfering control to the detail page');      
  }

  location.href='testSliderDAdultd.html';
}
function loadFnct() {
    $("h5").css("font-size", "11pt");
}
</script>
</head> 
<body onLoad="loadFnct();"> 

<div id="page" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Shots Lite</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a onClick="procClick(0);">19-21 Years</a></li>
            <li><a onClick="procClick(1);">22-26 Years</a></li>
            <li><a onClick="procClick(2);">27-49 Years</a></li>
            <li><a onClick="procClick(3);">50-59 Years</a></li>
            <li><a onClick="procClick(4);">60-64 Years</a></li>
            <li><a onClick="procClick(4);">Over 64 Years</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h5>Society of Teachers of Family Medicine</h5>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Two</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Content     
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Three</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Content     
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page4">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Four</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Content     
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This code actually is just code that originated from Dreamweaver's "Page from Sample"|"Mobile starter"|"jQuery Mobile (Local)"|"HTML5" starter template with a list added to the first page and a few other minor edits.  It still even has divs for "page2", "page3" and "page4" from the original template pattern that are no longer used.

And here is what the App store says that it looks like.  Their image was 960x640, so I assume that it was from the standard defintion iPhone.:

[image with no problems http://html6store.com/AppStore9.17.2013.png](http://html6store.com/AppStore9.17.2013.png)

So, it looks like jquery mobile has rendered the page approximately 3.3 times as wide as it should have when it was uploaded to the App Store, but it displays at the correct magnification everywhere I can test it at.  What is wrong?  How can I view the problem, fix and test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is going on here.  We submitted our app 3 weeks ago.  Three days ago, Apple released a stable version of xCode for iOS 7 to the developer community.  Apparently, the review process has been using the version that they just release to developers for a few weeks now.  I discovered this after upgrading my iPad to iOS7, then being forced to upgrade xCode to support iOS7 before I could use it further for testing.

iOS 7 adds the capability of running iPhone only apps on the iPad and there is a bug in iOS 7 that renders HTML wrong.  The simple solution to this problem (at least for me) was to officially support iPads (add icons, settings, etc.)

Under iOS7, the app is going to run on iPads, whether I want it to or not.  For me, I have been trying unsuccessfully to get the full app through the review process and I wanted to eliminate all possible obstacles to the lite version getting to the store, so I had figured that not supporting iPads eliminated one potential obstacle...little did I know.